# Custom AuthorizeAttribute Roles property is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implement RoleAuthorize class from AuthorizeAttribute

```
public sealed class RoleAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var roles = Roles;

        return false;
    }
}
```

But when filter occurred property Roles is null.
Thanks.

Comment: I know this is from a _long_ time ago, but did you ever figure this out?  Got the same issue.

Answer (score -3):

Did you apply the filter in the action method, like this?

```
[RoleAuthorize(Roles = "MyRole")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
         return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did apply like this